# Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object] in authGuard

Tags: angular, typescript

I am implementing authGuard on my app. But i keep getting error.

This is my guard

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    /**
     * returning an observable of type boolean is the correct way
     * to handle can activate that needs to wait for an observable result.
     */
    // 1. Select the authConfig from the store
    return this.getAuthentication()
      .pipe(
        // 2. Take the first instance.
        take(1),
        // 3. map the observable to an observable of type boolean
        // !! turns the value into a booleanca
        map((auth: AuthConfig) => !!(auth && auth.success === true)),
        // 4. if not authenticated then redirect the user.
        tap((auth: boolean) => this.redirectUserIfUnauthenticated(auth, this.getRedirectUrl(route))),
        // catch any errors and handle them.
        catchError((...args) => this.handleError.apply(this, args))
      )
  }
```

This is my getAuthentication

```
private getAuthentication(): Observable<AuthConfig> {
    return zip(
      this.store.select(ngrxTypes.authConfig),
      this.store.select(ngrxTypes.optionsConfig)
    ).pipe(
      mergeMap((configurations: [AuthConfig, OptionsConfig]) => this.getAuthenticationStatus(configurations)),
      mergeMap((authConfig: AuthConfig) => this.setAuthenticationStatus(authConfig))
    );
  }
```

This is where i perform http get method

```
private getAuthenticationStatus([auth, config]: [AuthConfig, OptionsConfig]): Observable<AuthConfig> {
    if (auth) {
      return this.store.select(ngrxTypes.authConfig);
    } else {
      const token = this.storageService.getCookie('token');
      const apiUrl = `${environment.user_profile_domain_url || config.user_profile_domain_url}/widgets/api/auth`;
      if (config && token) {
        return this.http.get(apiUrl, this.storageService.getHeader('Bearer', token))
          .map(login => login.json())
      } else {
        this.store.dispatch(this.authActions.setAuthConfig({success: false}));
        return this.store.select(ngrxTypes.authConfig);
      }
    }
  }
```

As I go with the process it keeps me having this error. I don't have idea why this happens everytime.

[image]

Comment: What version of Rxjs are you using? Can you please check it in your package.json and update the question?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I am using rxjs 5.0.1

Comment: @RafrafdelaCruz Are you using above code in some guard [i.e. canActivate method]?

Comment: @user2216584 yes exactly i was using it in guard.

Comment: @raf if it is guard and your canActivate returning promise then you should not throwError instead you should resolve the promise with false value. Looks like Angular’s guard implementation is not handling the exception. Once you resolve the promise with false it should be fine. Looks like you are returning an observable then simply return false wrapper in an observable instead of throwError. Can you share the code for guard?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get it. Can you explain more.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a misunderstanding of how Promises work or how to handle error inside them.

In the provided sample code, when you receive the response (401 error) you are handling that one in the "catch" handler, but when the **if** condition is met (you received a 401 error) you throw another error **which is not being handled**, since there is not other catch handler after that. Thus, leaving an error unhandled in an still not resolved promise.

It looks like you wanted to throw the error (when 401 is received) to be captured by the code calling the function where you make the http get, but you are throwing the error inside the promise, making the promise fail because of the unhandled error.

Comment: I see. This helps a lot. Thanks.